# Dynamically filter year which also contains text

Tags: excel, vba

The column `Q` that I am trying to filter has category called `2018 Complete` present as *string*. I have been looking for answers to see how could I filter out `2018 Complete` if I was in `2019` and `2019 Complete` if I was in `2020`. I did make a code but it does not work. Is there a way I can make it more dynamic so, if I was present in any other year I could still use it?

```
With Sheets("Valve List")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=" & Year(Date) - 1 & " & "Complete"
End With
```

The Code works just fine If I use it with only text:

```
.Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="2018 Complete"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the criteria to

```
With Sheets("Valve List")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= Year(date) -1 & " Complete"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works. Just curious to know why didn't my code work?

Comment: You were surrounding the date function with quote signs. So basically the filter was literally the text: Year(Date) - 1 Complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help but, I can't mark the answer as I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: No worries. Great to hear that it helped.